# Brighter Yellow for CSS Style Element .question-status

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I was recently reading a question that was **put on hold due to .....** and realised that authors may not be aware that their question is actually in a non-open state.

The information box is displayed in a light off-yellow-orange colour as can be seen below:

[image: picture of question status box with an off-yellow coloured background]

Wouldn't it be better to have this information displayed with a slightly more aggressive colour? Example attached below:

[image: picture of question status box with a bright yellow coloured background]

Currently I am achieving this with a user script created for the sole purpose of overriding the current CSS styles defined in the DBA.SE specific style sheet located at: https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/dba/primary.css

My user script modifies the `.question-status` element to be displayed in a bright yellow:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         StackExchange hot2use's modifications
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Modify various .CSS settings
// @author       hot2use
// == Matches Sites
// @match        *://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match        *://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match        *://*.superuser.com/*
// @match        *://*.serverfault.com/*
// @match        *://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @match        *://*.stackapps.com/*
// @match        *://*.mathoverflow.net/*
// @match        *://github.com/soscripted/*
// @match        *://soscripted.github.io/sox/*

// @grant        ...
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Your code here...
    function addGlobalStyle(css) {
    var head, style;
    head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    if (!head) { return; }
    style = document.createElement('style');
    style.type = 'text/css';
    style.innerHTML = css;
    head.appendChild(style);
}


    addGlobalStyle('.question-status{margin-top:15px;margin-bottom:10px;padding:15px 8px 1px 60px;background-color:#fff200;border:1px solid rgba(83,90,96,0.1);clear:both}');
})();
```

Comment: The css used for this is used across the entire network and I really doubt we'd adjust it to something specific for this site, not only that it's entirely too bright. I'd stick with the user script to adjust as you wish.

Comment: @Taryn Yes, I agree that my bright yellow might not be the best result, but a tad brighter than what we have now would be nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ...authors may not be aware that their question is actually in a non-open state

This is the crux of the matter. Never mind the colour of the banner, or whether it flashes or not.

The issue has been covered many times on meta.SE:

- [Send authors an inbox message if their question is put on hold](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93842/send-authors-an-inbox-message-if-their-question-is-put-on-hold) (and linked duplicates)

My voting history indicates that I supported this idea in the past (as have many others), but I am much less keen now:

Generally speaking, only **poor questions get placed on hold**, then closed, and ultimately deleted.

How much should we care about rescuing poor questions? Probably not much. A bit, maybe.

If the author responds positively to comments, the question will be improved to the point where it can be reopened. Even without comments, the author should notice the lack of answers, discover the banner, follow the links, improve the question...and so on.

If a person isn't invested enough in their own poor quality question to notice a (ok, pale) yellow banner, perhaps we shouldn't worry too much on their behalf either.

Find a better question to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Not a bad idea; although that may be a bit bright in my opinion.